# how to add style to span like .attr('style', 'width:newWidth '); where newWidth is dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a code like below

```
var newWidth = Math.floor(width * .75) + 'px';
$(this).find("input:first").attr('style', 'width:newWidth ');
```

could you please correct me as what should be the right syntax as passing newWidth directly is not working also I have to do this via style only

Comment: You literally have the answer to your question in the first line of your example. [String Operators at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/String_Operators)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.css()`

```
$(this).find("input:first").css('width', newWidth);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `css` method for this:

```
$(this).find("input:first").css('width', <your dynamic value> + 'px');
```

Here is a link to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

Otherwise, if you must use `attr` you should be able to do this:

```
$(this).find("input:first").attr('style', 'width:' + <your dynamic value> + 'px');
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in another answer, you can use [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

```
var newWidth = Math.floor(width * .75) + 'px';
$(this).find("input:first").css({
    width: newWidth
});
```

Or you can use [`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/), since you are using px units:

```
var newWidth = Math.floor(width * .75);
$(this).find("input:first").width(newWidth);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try this
 `.css("width","500px")`

Comment: There's nothing wrong with overwriting the `style` attribute directly, you definitely *are* able to do it, and there are situations where that is the correct thing to do.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
$(this).find("input:first").attr('style', 'width:'+newWidth+'px');
```